# PHP: Check if array contains part of a value

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays:

```
$array_a = array(
    array(
      "id" => 1,
      "merchant_reference" => "Ref 12345"
    ),
    array(
      "id" => 2,
      "merchant_reference" => "Ref 67890"
    ),
    array(
      "id" => 3,
      "merchant_reference" => "Ref 11122"
    )
  );

  $array_b = array(
    array(
      "id" => 1,
      "merchant_reference" => "12345"
    ),
    array(
      "id" => 2,
      "merchant_reference" => "67890"
    ),
    array(
      "id" => 3,
      "merchant_reference" => "11122"
    )
  );
```

And, I'm trying to find `12345` in '$array_b' since `Ref 12345` in '$array_a' contains '12345'.

I tried:

```
  $matches = array_filter($array_b, fn($item) => false !== strpos($item['merchant_reference'], $array_a[0]["merchant_reference"]));
  if (!!$matches!== false) {   
      echo "Exists";
  } else {
      echo "Does not exist";
  }
```

But, this does not work since I'm searching for more characters than are in '$array_b'

Comment: `if ($matches)` is enough.

Comment: @MarkusZeller, I still get 'Does not exist' if I do that.

Comment: Yes, because your filter is wrong. See my answer.

Comment: @MarkusZeller, have seen your answer - partially works. Please look at the comment.

Comment: Read my replies to your comment. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching the complete text including the "Ref ". Use a regex for extracting the number.

```
$matches = [];
preg_match('/Ref (\d+)/', $array_a[0]['merchant_reference'], $matches);
$searchRefNumber = $matches[1];

$matches = array_filter($array_b, fn($item) => $searchRefNumber === $item['merchant_reference']);

echo $matches ? 'Exists' : 'Does not exist';
```

prints

```
Exists
```

Comment: this works to remove the 'Ref' part and extract the number. But, what if I search for something like 'f 12345'? I'd still like to get `Exists`.

Comment: That was your question. So I answered it. You need to bit more preceisly then in asking.

Comment: You can adopt the pattern to get just the number and ignore anything else `preg_match('/(\d+)/', 'f 12345', $matches);` If it must match "f 12345" (not only numbers) you need to filter array_a first to look if it exists there, then compare to array_b.

Comment: Comment above worked perfectly, thanks.